# Fire Function on Window Resize

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function that resizes/equalizes elements so that they are the same size. I call that function on DOM Ready and I want to call it on window resize as well, but it doesn't seem to be firing. The `console.log` fires like you'd expect but not the `equalize()` function.

```
// Equalize
var equalize = function(){
  var maxHeight = 0;
  $('.equalize').each(function(){
    if ($(this).outerHeight() > maxHeight) { maxHeight = $(this).outerHeight(); }
  });

  $('.equalize').outerHeight(maxHeight);
};


jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {

  // fire equalize
  equalize();

  $(window).resize(function(){
    equalize();
    console.log('[Log] Resized');
  }).trigger('resize');

});
```

Am I missing something here when it comes to firing functions on window resize? Thanks!

Comment: Seems to work just fine for me ?

Comment: Are you sure both snippets above are in the same scope? If so, and if the console log output is present, then your `equalize()` function is definitely being called.

Comment: This snippet above is the entire `js` file @StephenThomas

Comment: @adeneo the `console.log` fires but the equalize function that resizes the elements does not.

Comment: Try adding a `console.log` to the beginning and end of the equalize function and try resizing the window to see if they are in fact being called. If they are then the problem is your logic.

Comment: Have you tried any console.log() statements inside the equalize() function? The function must be called and return without error, otherwise it wouldn't get as far as the console.log() after the function call.

Comment: I wonder if the `.trigger('resize')` on the resize function is causing a problem. Why is that there?? You are calling resize when the window is resized, then calling resize then that function ends again, does this cause an infinite loop??

Comment: As noted by others, either the `equalize()` function is being called, or it would throw an error because the function is undefined, and the console.log below wouldn't work

Comment: @Radmation - it's not a loop, the trigger is just triggering the resize handler once on pageload

Comment: @adeneo but he is calling the equalizer function on load as well??

Comment: @Radmation - he is, but it's still not a loop. Both the `equalize` function and the event handler that calls the `equalize` function, is called on pageload, but that's not really problem, other than the function being called twice.

Comment: @adeneo I still think it would cause a loop.

Comment: @Radmation - And I'm telling you it wouldn't, as the `equalize` function doesn't retrigger anything that would call the `equalize` function again.

Comment: I'll even prove it, and that the code works fine -> **https://jsfiddle.net/xv9ceuo6/**

Comment: @adeneo Yup i was wrong. Well the problem then must be the logic, cause the function gets called fine.

Comment: @adeneo  - i think we are sort of missing the point here, I understand the function is firing and that the console logs are working. But why are the items not resizing? See this fiddle for an example -> https://jsfiddle.net/4tLuyz3g/1/

Comment: @adeneo And yes, the function gets called twice because the elements need to be equalized once on page load, and then my intended functionality is for them to update their heights when resized because the content will begin to spill out when the browser window is reduced.

Comment: Your function works just as intended, but the original element doesn't resize because it doesn't have `overflow : auto` -> https://jsfiddle.net/4tLuyz3g/2/

Comment: Oh, and the logic is flawed, you can't include elements that auto resize, and explicitly set the height, then they won't auto resize anymore -> https://jsfiddle.net/4tLuyz3g/3/

Comment: @adeneo Boom. If you want to make that an answer thats what I'm looking for.

Comment: Actually, with a little trickery, you could include both elements in the logic -> https://jsfiddle.net/4tLuyz3g/4/

Comment: @buschschwick - posted an answer, feel free to accept it !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For an element to resize so it fits the content, the style `overflow : auto` has to be set, otherwise the element just keeps it's size and the content overflows.

Also, when you explicitly set the `outerHeight`, the elements stops auto-resizing to fit the content, the default height of `auto` has to be applied to trick it into resizing before the elements heights are compared

```js
var equalize = function() {
    var max = Math.max.apply(null, 
                $('.equalize').css('height', 'auto').map(function() {
                    return $(this).outerHeight();
                })
              );
    $('.equalize').outerHeight(max);
};


jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(window).resize(function() {
        equalize();
    }).trigger('resize');
});
```

```css
div{
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  background: yellow;
}

.other{
  background: salmon;
  overflow:auto;
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/4tLuyz3g/5/)

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the trigger see if that helps. According to jQuery doc the trigger fires an even (calls a function)

I don't think it makes sense to call a function then after the function is called, trigger it again, then that should go on forever....may be the cause of the problem.

```
// Equalize
var equalize = function(){
  var maxHeight = 0;
  $('.equalize').each(function(){
    if ($(this).outerHeight() > maxHeight) { maxHeight = $(this).outerHeight(); }
  });

  $('.equalize').outerHeight(maxHeight);
};


jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {

  // fire equalize
  equalize();

  $(window).resize(function(){
    equalize();
    console.log('[Log] Resized');
  }); // got rid of the trigger...not needed

});
```

Comment: The `console.log` fires, but the function that resizes the elements do not.

Comment: @buschschwick Try putting the `console.log` inside the `equalize` function as the first line to see if maybe it is firing, just not working.

Answer (score 0):

It's a little hard to say without some more detail about what's going on in your project, but this works for me (at least to get equalize to fire on window resize):

```
var equalize = function(){
  var maxHeight = 0;
  $('.equalize').each(function(){
    if ($(this).outerHeight() > maxHeight) { maxHeight = $(this).outerHeight(); }
  });

  $('.equalize').outerHeight(maxHeight);
};


jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {
  equalize();

  $(window).resize(function(){
    equalize();
    console.log('[Log] Resized');
  })

});
```